Product of RVs of Which Distribution Approximates Normal Well?
Suppose that I have $N$ i.i.d. random variables with a distribution $Q$, which has mean around 1. That is $R_1, R_2,\ldots,R_N \sim Q$. I would like $\prod_{i=1}^N R_i$ to approximate a normal random variable.
What are some candidate distributions for $Q$ so that I get a reasonable approximation as $N$ gets larger?

If $\psi_0(t)=\mathbb E_{\mathcal N(0,1)}[X^t]$ and $\psi_1(t)=\mathbb E_Q[R^t]$, $Q$ is defined by the functional equation$$\psi_1(t)=\psi_0(t)^{1/N}\qquad t\ge 0$$

@Xi'an you mean 1/t instead of 1/N?

No,the equation follows from$$\mathbb E_{Q^{\otimes N}}[(R_1\cdots R_N)^t]=\mathbb E_Q[R_1^t]\cdots\mathbb E_Q[R_N^t]=\psi_1(t)^N$$

What @Xi'an gives is the Mellin transform  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mellin_transform

So long a partial answer, using the Mellin transform. We use the definition of Mellin transform of a probability density on the non-negative real axis
$$ \DeclareMathOperator{\M}{\mathcal{M}} 
\M(X)(s) = \int_0^\infty x^s f(x) \; dx $$
where $f$ is the density function of the random variable $X$.
Your random variables are defined on the real axis, but are symmetric there, so we reduce to the non-negative axis by multiplication with Rademacher variables, that is, random variables taking the values $\pm 1$ with equal probability. So write $R_i = S_i T_i$, where the factors are independent, $S_i$ (sign) is Rademacher and $T_i$ is standard half-normal (the absolute value of a standard normal).
Then $\prod_1^n R_i = \prod_1^n S_i \prod_1^n T_i$ and since the product of $n$ independent rademacher variables again is Rademacher, we get
$$ \prod_1^n R_i = S \prod_1^n T_i
$$ where $S$ is Rademacher. Since a standard normal random variable is the independent product of a Rademacher variable and a half-normal random variable, your question is reduced to ask for a distribution such that the product of $n$ independent copies is half-normal.
The Mellin transform of a half-normal variable $N$ is
$$ \M(N)(s) = \int_0^\infty x^s \sqrt{2/\pi} e^{-x^2/2}\; dx \\
 = \frac{2^{s/2} \Gamma(\frac{s+1}{2})}{\sqrt{\pi}} 
$$
and the Mellin transform of $T_i$ is then the $n$th root of this
$$ \M(T_i)(s) = \left( \frac{2}{\pi}  \right)^{s/2n} \Gamma\left(\frac{s+1}{2}\right)^{1/n}.
$$
But the question remains how to invert this, exactly or approximately ...

This is a very useful starting point thank you.

See this 2001 paper by Tagilani that addresses the recovery.

Paradoxically, Luc Devroye has a paper with Lancelot Jams specifically on Mellin transforms and simulation of stable laws, but they do not use the Mellin transform in their simulation algorithms.

The link for Tagliani paper is broken

@CagdasOzgenc: Can it be https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S009630030100114X ?
